# Using $translate in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the text defined in our translations.js file in order to pass it to an angular-bootstrap alert as its text. I've injected the $translate service into the controller and am using the $translate service like so:

```
$translate('TXT_ALERT_MSG').then(function (translation) {
        $log.debug( translation );
});
```

but it breakes angular and states the following error message:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

This is thrown on the very first line of the code above. I wrapped it in a promise to make sure i only print the value upon successfully retrieving the translation. I also tried assigning the value to a variable but this throws the same error:

```
function getTranslation() {
        var msg = $translate('TXT_ALERT_MSG');
        $log.debug(msg);
    }
    getTranslation();
```

This is most likely something simple so what is it?

Thanks

**EDIT**
How I inject the translate module into the app:

```
angular.module('MainApp',['pascalprecht.translate']);
```

and how it's configured:

```
angular.module('MainApp').config(['$translateProvider', 'ConfigProvider', function ($translateProvider, ConfigProvider) {
var config = ConfigProvider.$get();
var rootUrl = config.get('ourRootUrl');

$translateProvider.translations('en', {

    // all our translations e.g.
    TIMED_OUT_BUTTON: 'Return to Dashboard'

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

}]);
```

Comment: How do you inject $translate ? do you declare the translate module ?

Comment: $translate is injected into the controller in the normal way. It is declared as a dependency on the app as 'pascalprecht.translate' - see my edit

Comment: Show the skeleton of the factory that defines the `$translate` service. Also, off-topic, `$` (just like `ng` prefix) typically should be reserved for future Angular services. You should come up with your own prefix.

Comment: @NewDev $translate isn't something I've created - its part of angular-translate: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service

Comment: Ah, I see... well, I don't think your bug is evident in the code you posted. Post a plunker with your code, and we'll try to find what the problem is

Comment: Can you show how you `config` your `'$translateProvider` in your app?

Comment: Sorry I added the comment before the edit

Comment: And how are you loading translations? Static files maybe? Since, all translations here is a bad idea in case you have a lot of translations.

Comment: And I'm not sure what is `ConfigProvider` used for, do you need it?

Comment: @AniketSinha all our translations are in that .js file. We do need it but I'm not sure exactly what we need it for though

Comment: Assuming your `ConfigProvider` is not breaking the app, your code looks good. Can you create a plunker? It'll be a real help in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get the translations by translate filter

```
$filter('translate')('TIMED_OUT_BUTTON')
```